# Why the color of the pie doesn't change?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm a beginner in d3.js. Today, when I learned how to picture a pie map, the color of the pie doesn't change. But I fill it according to the introduction of the d3 v4. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>pie map</title>
</head>
 
<body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
        var width = 400;        
        var height = 400;    
        var dataset = [30,10,43,55,13];
        var svg = d3.select("body")    
                    .append("svg")     
                    .attr("width",width)      
                    .attr("height",height);     

        var pie=d3.pie();
        var piedata=pie(dataset);
        var outerRadius=150;
        var innerRadius=0;

        var arc=d3.arc()
                .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                .outerRadius(outerRadius);

        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategoty10);

        var arcs=svg.selectAll("g")
                .data(piedata)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform","translate("+ (width/2) +","+ (width/2) +")");


            arcs.append("path")
                .attr("fill",function(d,i){
                    return color[i];  //to fill color
                })
                .attr("d",function(d){
                    return arc(d);
                });


            arcs.append("text")
                .attr("transform",function(d){
                    return "translate("+arc.centroid(d)+")";
                })
                .attr("text-anchor","middle")
                .text(function(d){
                    return d.data;
                });
        console.log(dataset);
        console.log(piedata);
    </script>     
</body>
</html>
```

I want to picture a pie map like this:
[image]

but mine is this:
[image]

so I'm confused, because there is no error in console. Do you know why the color doesn't appear in my pie map? I'm very appreciate if you help me solve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was 2 errors in your code

1. A typo with `var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategoty10);` instead of `var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);` -- the **r** of **categoRy**
2. You were using

   `return color[i];  //to fill color`
   instead of 
   `return color(i);  //to fill color`

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>pie map</title>
</head>
 
<body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
        var width = 400;        
        var height = 400;    
        var dataset = [30,10,43,55,13];
        var svg = d3.select("body")    
                    .append("svg")     
                    .attr("width",width)      
                    .attr("height",height);     

        var pie=d3.pie();
        var piedata=pie(dataset);
        var outerRadius=150;
        var innerRadius=0;

        var arc=d3.arc()
                .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                .outerRadius(outerRadius);

        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

        var arcs=svg.selectAll("g")
                .data(piedata)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform","translate("+ (width/2) +","+ (width/2) +")");


            arcs.append("path")
                .attr("fill",function(d,i){
                    return color(i);  //to fill color
                })
                .attr("d",function(d){
                    return arc(d);
                });


            arcs.append("text")
                .attr("transform",function(d){
                    return "translate("+arc.centroid(d)+")";
                })
                .attr("text-anchor","middle")
                .text(function(d){
                    return d.data;
                });
    </script>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you~~It can work! It was so careless of me! Thank you~~

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 possible solutions after solve the typo mistake in **d3.schemeCategoty10** to **d3.schemeCategory10**:

1. You could try to remove the scale ordinal from `var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategoty10);` to `var color = d3.schemeCategory10;`
2. If you want it as an ordinal scale you should change `return color[i];` to `return color(i);`

This will be the result for the first solution:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>pie map</title>
</head>
 
<body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
        var width = 400;        
        var height = 400;    
        var dataset = [30,10,43,55,13];
        var svg = d3.select("body")    
                    .append("svg")     
                    .attr("width",width)      
                    .attr("height",height);     

        var pie=d3.pie();
        var piedata=pie(dataset);
        var outerRadius=150;
        var innerRadius=0;

        var arc=d3.arc()
                .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                .outerRadius(outerRadius);

        var color = d3.schemeCategory10;

        var arcs=svg.selectAll("g")
                .data(piedata)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform","translate("+ (width/2) +","+ (width/2) +")");


            arcs.append("path")
                .attr("fill",function(d,i){
                    return color[i];  //to fill color
                })
                .attr("d",function(d){
                    return arc(d);
                });


            arcs.append("text")
                .attr("transform",function(d){
                    return "translate("+arc.centroid(d)+")";
                })
                .attr("text-anchor","middle")
                .text(function(d){
                    return d.data;
                });
    </script>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help~~But it still doesn't work when I infer to your introduction. Besides, If I use your code, an error appears:Uncaught TypeError: color is not a function

Comment: It's working in the snippet, you should be able to run it. Anyway you could try the second solution (Remember that I told you 2 solutions, not 2 steps, choose one of those). Good luck anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your help~~Now, it can work, thank you~~

Comment: I feel sorry for misunderstanding your answer.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not terribly familiar with D3, it's possible that your problem is a simple typo. Try changing

```
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategoty10);
```

to:

```
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help! But your code can not solve my problem, and I use your code before asking this question.